# in jQuery, is it possible to halt execution until a user submits a value in a jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I have an event handler for   `$('.toggle-enable-item').click(functi ....`  which does an ajax request and a set of associated callbacks. I would like to just add one for   `$('.toggle-enable-menu-item .with-comment').click(fun...` and set the textarea for that comment to a window.unenable_comment.

However, the event for .with-comment just proceeds through. Is there a way to tell Javascript to halt execution until the user clicks the button for 'Add Comment Item'? Ideally, I'd like this to cascade into the 'toggle-enable-item'. FWIW, the prompt call seems to halt execution correctly.

Is this happening because the event is being bubbled up? Is there a way I can prevent this bubbling and just make the ajax call separately?

non-enabled:

```
<li data-id="1709" data-status="not-enabled" class="toggle-enable-item">enable</li>
```

enabled:

```
<li class="toggle-enable-item" data-id="1710" data-status="enabled">
unenable
<span class="with-comment">with comment</span>
</li>
```

thx

Comment: You can use `on()` and `off()` with event namespaces to run events whenever you want. Look into it in the API

Comment: thx - looks like on / off is replacing a lot of what I've been using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent bubbling by using `event.stopPropagation()` in the `$('.toggle-enable-menu-item .with-comment').click(function(event){` Then after the user clicks the button `trigger` a click on `toggle-enable-item`

Comment: If it helped then please mark as answered when you get the chance, thanks!

Comment: sorry, thought that I clicked